# Tagging work items in TFS 2010

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

are there known ways to tag work items in TFS 2010? What type of field do I need to add, where the user can select different tags for a work item from a list of recommended tags and type in new tags for that list?

Comment: For what purpose you want that? To make custom work item queries made on a given tag value?

Comment: Yes, to group work items beyond their association with a parent work item. E.g. all work items affecting "design" or all items affecting "refactoring-step1".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no support for tags as you know and love it from other products like Stack Overflow. It is high on our wish list though ...

Answer (score 1):

The ability to tag work items is available in TFS 2013.

Answer (score 0):

[Someone](http://elegantcode.com/2008/04/21/tagging-team-system-work-items/) suggested a single text field with space-separated keywords.  This certainly isn't as good as built-in tagging support, but it might do.  I'm also looking for a better solution.  I wonder if TFS 2012 has anything new in this area?